# How to make a list of lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I use SWI-Prolog and I want to make a list of several other lists.

For example, I want to put the following three lists

```
[a,b,c]
[1,2]
[d]
```

into a larger one that looks like `[[a,b,c],[1,2],[d]]` .

```
divideList([]):-!.

divideList([Head|Tail]):-
    list_to_set(Head,H),%H is a List 
    divideList(Tail).
```

I want to put all H in one list.
How can I do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you have a fixed number of lists that you want to put into one list ?

Comment: Yes, I have three list but it can be change. I want to put them in larger one.

Comment: Assuming the three lists are unified with the variables A,B,C then you would just write [A,B,C]

Comment: Yes, similarly. I have a recursive loop, in every iteration I calculate H variable. (H looks like [a,b,c]). And I want to put in a large one after loop. Like [[a,b],[a,b,c]].

Comment: divideList([]):-!.

    divideList([Head|Tail]):-
 list_to_set(Head,H),
 divideList(Tail). My code like this. H is a list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using H in your predicate to put the list you want

This should do it

```
divideList([], []):-!.
divideList([Head|Tail], [H|HTail]):-
    list_to_set(Head,H),%H is a List 
    divideList(Tail, HTail).
```

The second argument will have your list of lists.

Comment: @larsman: Right, but I just added what was missing in OP code, so I left it as the way it was.